# Is there a linux command loop through files in a directory then write all files names and content into csv file?

Tags: linux, file

I have a directory with 100 thousand files (each file has only one line), I need a fast way to go through all files to write one csv file that contains two columns: File Name, Content of the File.

File_A:
This is File one.

File_B:
This is file two.

I need to get a csv file:
File_A This is File one.
File_B This is file two.

Comment: Just use: `grep . *`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do `grep . * > ../output.csv` to create a file with a `:` separator.  If you want to use a different delimiter, pipe it to `sed`. Some grep provide a `--null` option to use a zero byte as the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you this does exactly what I need